# JS NG2 Firebase - Add foreach values to array and use in template

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to create an array of room names and feed it to and ngFor in my template. The values push into the array but it looks like they are only available while within the foreach.. I need to have them available in the template also.. here is my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import { Fb } from './firebase';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'page-message-overview',
  templateUrl: 'message-overview.html'
})

export interface ChatThreadOverview {
  roomname: string;
}

export class MessageOverviewPage {

  activeUser: string;
  threads:  FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  fb;
  af;
  public chatroom: ChatThreadOverview[] = [];

  constructor( public fire: Fb, af: AngularFire, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.fb         = fire.instance().database();
        this.af = af;
        this.activeUser = this.fire.instance().auth().currentUser.uid;

        this.threads = this.af.database.list('/message/u_'+ this.activeUser, { preserveSnapshot: true });
        this.threads.subscribe(snapshots => {
            snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
              // console.log(snapshot.key)
              this.chatroom.push({ "roomname": snapshot.val().room });
              console.log( "Chat inside "+ JSON.stringify(this.chatroom ) )
            });
          })
          console.log( "Chat outside "+ JSON.stringify(this.chatroom ) );
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() { }

}
```

Just to clarify there is 2 console outputs basically the one outside the foreach fires first and the array is empty  the one within the foreach fires each time with the value.. i need this value to be available outside the foreach loop

Comment: The values ARE available after the data has been retrieved. If you want to use it in view, you could wrap it in `<div *ngIf="chatroom">` for example.

Comment: `console.log( "Chat outside "+ JSON.stringify(this.chatroom ) );` will prints undefined, because you're printing outside the `subscribe` method and it's `async`, but as @AJT_82 mentioned, in template it's avalaible or inside the `subscribe` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous call, so as you noticed, the values are not instantly available and that `console.log( "Chat outside "+ JSON.stringify(this.chatroom ) );` gets executed before the code inside the subscription. One solution is to wrap the code that concerns `chatroom` inside a div with the condition that the part of template is only displayed if there are values in `chatroom`. So something like:

```
<div *ngIf="chatroom">
   <!-- your code here -->
</div>
```

This removes the div from the view unless there is no values in chatroom. We are though assuming that the values will be available at some time :)

This way your app will not throw an undefined error. You will get used to using this trick, since we are constantly dealing with async "issues" in Angular, most commonly that view gets rendered before the data has been retrieved, resulting the breaking of the app.

Other possibility than the `*ngIf` is to use the safe navigation operator, more about that [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) That's another useful thing to use. With that you can use e.g like:

```
<div *ngFor="let room of chatroom">
  <p>{{room?.yourProp}}</p>
</div>
```

where `yourProp` is some property of a single `room`.